# Problem with writing a file on a certain path

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os, python-aiofiles

I try to write the file to disk by specifying the path to the folder to save. But I get the error of reading the file by the specified path.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/jekson/Projects/img-text-reco/static/product_images/24f2a9d0372a49bc8c5eb259798477f0.jpeg'
```

Error occurs in this line.

```
async with aiofiles.open(os.path.join(IMG_DIR, file_name)) as f
```

For clarity, I made a print call indicating the paths in the body function

```
from db import BASEDIR

print(BASEDIR) # /home/jekson/Projects/img-text-reco

def file_upload():
    ....
    IMG_DIR = os.path.join(BASEDIR, 'static/product_images')
    if not os.path.exists(IMG_DIR):
        os.makedirs(IMG_DIR)
    print(f'IMG_DIR {IMG_DIR}') # IMG_DIR /home/jekson/Projects/img-text-reco/static/product_images
    content = await file.read()
    if file.content_type not in ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=406, detail="Only .jpeg or .png  files allowed")
    file_name = f'{uuid.uuid4().hex}{ext}'
    print(os.path.join(IMG_DIR, file_name)) # /home/jekson/Projects/img-text-reco/static/product_images/24f2a9d0372a49bc8c5eb259798477f0.jpeg
    async with aiofiles.open(os.path.join(IMG_DIR, file_name)) as f:
        await f.write(content)
    path_to_img = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(IMG_DIR, file_name))
    ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open the file for reading and it doesn't exist, hence the error. The following `f.write` suggests that you want to open the file for writing instead:

```py
async with aiofiles.open(os.path.join(IMG_DIR, file_name), mode='w') as f:
```

Comment: That's right. Didn't catch that. Thank you! In my case, I' ll have to use `wb`instead of `w`.